# xPath (SCRAPY) Python using two attributes together

Tags: python, xpath

For example :

```
<html >
  <body>
    <a class="abcd" title="he is Gandhi"> he was good </a>
    <a class="bcde" > he was very good </a>
    <a class="abcde" title ="Gandhi was "> good man </a>
  </body>
</html>
```

if here we want to display text in the above html where `class="abcde"` and title contains Gandhi using xpath in python how shall I do?

Answer (score 2):

You can filter based on `class` and `title` attributes like:

```
//a[@class='abcde' and contains(@title, 'Gandhi')]
```

This part `@class='abcde'` will match for the exact `class`, **then comes a logical** `and` along with `contains(@title, 'Gandhi')` xPath function which should match any element with `title` containing 'Gandhi'.

The main point is that you can use `and` and `or` logical expressions in xPath expressions to be able to combine different attributes.